# Debugging Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS in C

Tags: c

I have two variables:

- `totvowels`
- `totDigits`

to respectively count the number of vowels and digits in a string using call by reference. The build succeeds but when I try to run the program, there is no output.

Here is my main function given in the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void processString(char *str, int *totVowels, int *totDigits);
int main()
{
     char str[50], *p;
     int totVowels, totDigits;

     printf("Enter the string: \n");
     fgets(str, 80, stdin);

     if (p=strchr(str,'\n')) *p = '\0';
     processString(str, &totVowels, &totDigits); //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ffeefc00000) is shown// 
     printf("Total vowels = %d\n", totVowels);
     printf("Total digits = %d\n", totDigits);
     return 0;
}
```

I coded this function and I am guessing the error has something to do with my pointer variable, but not sure where:

```
void processString(char *str, int *totVowels, int *totDigits)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i =0; str[i] != "\0"; ++i){
        if(str[i]=="a" || str[i]=="e" || str[i] == "i" || str[i] == "o" || str[i] == "u" || str[i] == 'A' || str[i] == 'E' || str[i] == 'I' || str[i] == 'O' || str[i] == 'U')
            ++totVowels;
    }
    for (i =0; str[i] != "\0"; ++i){
        if (str[i] == "1" || str[i] == "2" || str[i] == "3" || str[i] == "4" || str[i]== "5" || str[i] == "6" || str[i] == "7" || str[i] == "8" || str[i] == "9" || str[i] == "0")
            ++totDigits;
    }
}
```

I am new with pointer manipulation and still confused as to whether I have actually initialized my pointers. Please help, thank you!

Comment: `++totVowels;` (and `++totDigits;`) increment the pointer, not the value stored at that address. Further,what are the values of the `int totVowels, totDigits;` when you call `processString()` (hint: the values are indeterminate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is are some typo in the program, I fix it below:

```
void processString(char *str, int *totVowels, int *totDigits)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i =0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if(str[i]=='a' || str[i]=='e' || str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o' || str[i] == 'u' || str[i] == 'A' || str[i] == 'E' || str[i] == 'I' || str[i] == 'O' || str[i] == 'U')
            ++totVowels;
    }
    for (i =0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if (str[i] == '1' || str[i] == '2' || str[i] == '3' || str[i] == '4' || str[i]== '5' || str[i] == '6' || str[i] == '7' || str[i] == '8' || str[i] == '9' || str[i] == '0')
            ++totDigits;
    }
}
```

In `C`, double-quoted things are strings. If you want to compare characters, you need to use single quotes such as `'e'` or `'\0'`

`"\0"` is a string of 2 NUL characters. This string is stored somewhere in memory, therefore "\0" point to a non-null address.

Another issue is related to pointers:

```
  ++totVowels;
```

This will move the local address of the pointer to the next adjacent address.  This will not change the value of the counter. To update the value from a pointer, you need to `derefence` the pointer with the `*pointer` operator:

```
*totVowels = *totVowels  + 1;
```

EDIT due to the informative comment of David C. Rankin

You also need to `initialize` the counters in the main program. In C, the local variables are not initialized, so their values are undefined.

```
int main()
{
     char str[50], *p;
     int totVowels = 0, totDigits = 0; // Here, need to initialize the counters
     printf("Enter the string: \n");
     fgets(str, 80, stdin);
     if (p=strchr(str,'\n')) *p = '\0';
     processString(str, &totVowels, &totDigits); //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ffeefc00000) is shown// 
     printf("Total vowels = %d\n", totVowels);
     printf("Total digits = %d\n", totDigits);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the initialized value of `totVowels` and `totDigits`? The access and use of the values would be *Undefined Behavior* if the values were indeterminate - No? Also, the increment of the pointers and subsequent attempt to access is the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. There is only one `int` value defined, when the pointer is incremented, it now points to an invalid address, hence `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I understand now that i was adding value to the address stored in the pointer instead of the value stored in the address. I got it!